# Конфигурация nginx для двух Node.js серверов

Tags: node.js, nginx, сервер

Есть **nginx** *и два сервера Node.js*.

главный сайт на ноде: nginx берет на себя статику - css,js,img,json.. в js происходит fetch - put/get/post запросы к серверу node.js, который возвращает, записывает данные, возвращает скомпилированные в html шаблоны pug, дает скачивать архивы с данными. А еще есть вообще отдельный сервер node.js рядом. К нему идет запрос и он возвращает данные, может быть использован на других сайтах по его апи.

```
/opt/website/
             - web-static-files
             - server: (/bin/www - старт 1сервера), (/service-server2/app.js - старт 2го сервера)
```

1сервер берет статические файлы с web, 2й сервер - из рядом - лежащей папки.

пытаюсь настроить конфиг как временный-дев, так и потом на http2/ssl итоговый.

etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx devname;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  sitename.ru 44.222.111.22;
    #_;
        root         /opt/sitename/web;
    #/usr/share/nginx/html;
    index        index.html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass         "http://44.222.111.22:3000";
            root                /opt/website/server
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

делаю сабмит-форм запрос на route 1сервера - не найдено, хотя нод запущен через node /bin/www

для нод я здесь верно указываю 44.222.111.22, или 127.0.0.1 нужно на рабочем сервере хостинга? сам нод сервер, вроде, без ошибки запустился и висит.

```
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
const = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: ничего не понятно. вообще. и `location ../server` выглядит смешно.

Answer (score 1):

Так как подробностей в вопросе мало то буду исходить из предположения, что есть 2 сервиса:

1. на порту 3001, занимается обработкой файлов
2. на порту 3000, отвечает за бизнес-логику

Конфиг в упрощённом виде:

```
http {
    index   index.html;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;

    upstream backend_files {
        server  127.0.0.1:3001;
    }

    upstream backend_api {
        server  127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  sitename.ru;

        # раздача статики
        location / {
            root /opt/website/server;
        }

        # всё, что связано с бэкендом на порту 3001
        location /api1/ {
            proxy_pass  http://backend_files;
        }

        # всё, что связано с бэкендом на порту 3000
        location /api2/ {
            proxy_pass  http://backend_api;
        }
    }
}
```

Естественно, в вашем случае это всё может не заработать, конфиг требует переделки под ваши нужны.

Comment: спасибо! днем попробую. если мало - уточняю: есть сайт на ноде. nginx берет на себя статику - css,js,img,json.. в js происходит fetch - put/get/post запросы к серверу node.js, который возвращает, записывает данные, возвращает скомпилированные в html шаблоны pug, дает скачивать архивы с данными. А еще есть вообще отдельный сервер node.js рядом. К нему идет запрос и он возвращает данные, может быть использован на других сайтах по его апи.

Comment: переделал немного ответ, чтобы более наглядно стало видно кто за что отвечает. но по вопросу (и предыдущему вопросу) я вижу, что ты совершенно не имеешь навыка настройки nginx, так что предлагаю не терять время на дурацкие эксперименты, а потратить полчаса на чтение: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html и http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: спасибо! доки внимательней гляну. Вообще,ньюанс в том, что 1-файлы статики, тот же индекс, есть рядом с папкой server - в папке web, хотя и можно их кинуть в 1 папку с сервером, хо желательно разделение 2- хотелось бы и статику, и главный бекенд вызывать с корня адреса сайта, то есть website.ru/index.html, website.ru/js/scr.js, website.ru/css/stl.css... и fetch('/callServerFunc1 -т.е. website.ru/callServerFunc1, 2,3 .. по сути